# Jquery plugins tend to make my browser window "reset/scrollup" whenever i use them... how can i stop this?

Tags: jquery, browser

Right now i'm just trying to do the transfer effect.  I have it working fine... but whenever I hit the "Add to Cart" button to do the transfer effect, my browser window scrolls all the way up.  It seems like using the effect causes the browser to reset it's y coordinate on the scroll bar...

Comment: Could you provide some code? It's hard to know what you're talking about without some code to look at.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. At least show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a link that has its HREF pointing to "#".

You should either remove the href:

```
$('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Or override it:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // your code goes here
});
```